# In Python biscuit_auth, how can I view biscuit datalog.facts without public key?

Tags: python

...for example on the home page of [biscuitsec.org](https://www.biscuitsec.org/), where you can drop a biscuit into their UI and it will decode and display facts, without needing a public key.

Here is a token that should have 4 facts in it:

```
biscuit_token = EvoBCo8BCg90ZXN0OmNhcGFiaWxpdHkKBkRFTEVURQoWbmFtZXNwYWNlLnNvbWVyZXNvdXJjZQoGSU5TRVJUCgZTRUxFQ1QKBlVQREFURRgDIg8KDQiACBIDGIEIEgMYgggiDwoNCIAIEgMYgwgSAxiCCCIPCg0IgAgSAxiECBIDGIIIIg8KDQiACBIDGIUIEgMYgggSJAgAEiBuhGUKrI9PAHllP7i97pRKuR3MMUYyf68OhqETL2SU-xpAx3EWdjFsaf2mOgU6Lt_VjM1HGTx1wBlwS8EtbWZJtiHQJuTVdpNP279mcPf9XDfs9mIP2Z-P-Iu9Ap6AJ4dmAiIiCiC60io01fNSwbqge12r_s5rD9IzVI70vcFoGvkaq_dqkw==
```

[biscuitsec.org](https://www.biscuitsec.org/) correctly returns (without public key):

```
test:capability("DELETE", "namespace.someresource");
test:capability("INSERT", "namespace.someresource");
test:capability("SELECT", "namespace.someresource");
test:capability("UPDATE", "namespace.someresource");
```

I'd assume there is a way to emulate this using python's biscuit_auth library, but I can't figure it out based on the [python documentation at biscuitsec.org](https://www.biscuitsec.org/blog/biscuit-python-0-2-0/).  I can create biscuits, validate and use biscuits given the public key, but wanted to provide a "sneak-peak" without public key validation.

To be clear, I'm not looking to validate the biscuit, just view the facts in an un-validated fashion.

Thanks!